# Test that React prop method has been called with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an Input component, which accepts a prop method and calls it when the user types something in. Code itself works as expected, but for some reasons, test fails. It thinks that prop method wasn't called. Why is it happening? For testing purposes, I use Jest and react-testing-library.

And second question. In real application, my idea is to test parameters that were passed to that prop method. Is it considered to be an implementation testing (I know that I should test it)?

> Input.js

```
export default function Input({ onChange }) {
  return <input onChange={onChange} />;
}
```

> Test

```
import React from "react";
import { render, act, cleanup, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";
import Input from "./input";

describe("Input tests", () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it("Should call prop function", () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Input onChange={onChange} />);
    const input = getByTestId("input");

    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Q" } });
    });

    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/y229669nvx

Comment: Because change means it's state has changed, if you want to trigger change, what about assign value directly such as input.value="xxx"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this, it looks like it's [by design to not assert against events handlers](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/175#issuecomment-422189880). Although it appears [to work in React 16.5](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn0wzonq94), however, using 16.8.x fails. I'd suggest moving to enzyme if you want to test such features.

Testing with `react-testing-library` fails (however, as you'll notice, when running the test, the input's value will actually change): https://codesandbox.io/s/n3rvy891n4

Testing with `enzyme` succeeds: https://codesandbox.io/s/lx34ny41nl

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I started thinking to switch to Enzyme as well, now I think I'll do it :)

Comment: To be honest, that's probably a better move. `react-testing-library` seems to complicate testing by forcing you to find by `data attributes` or by `text` within an `element`. While `enzyme` offers finding by `id`, `className`, `text`, `prop`, `element`, `component` ...etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, `data-testid` is considered the last resort when it comes to RTL. The preferred way to find an element is to look for text, labels or other things that the user will see

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your test doesn't work is that you're using `getByTestId` to find your element. `getByTestId` looks for a DOM node that has a `data-testid` attribute.

In order to make your test pass, you have various options.

You could add a `data-testid` to your `input`: `<input data-testid="input" onChange={onChange} />`. This would work, however, it's better to avoid test ids whenever you can.

In a real application, your input would be rendered with a `label`, we can take advantage of that:

```
const { getByLabelText } = render(
  <label>
    My input
    <Input onChange={onChange} />
  </label>
)
const input = getByLabelText('My input')
```

Another solution is to use `container` which is one one of the values returned by `render`. It's a DOM node—like everything else in RTL—so you can use the usual DOM APIs:

```
const { container } = render(<Input onChange={onChange} />)
// Any of these would work
const input = container.firstChild
const input = container.querySelector('input')
```

---

As a side note, I agree that RTL tests seem more complicated if compared to Enzyme. There's a good reason for it. RTL pushes you to test your application as if it were a black box. This is a bit harder to do in the beginning but ultimately leads to better tests.

Enzyme, on the other hand, mocks most things by default and allows you to interact with your components implementation. This, in my experience, looks easier in the beginning but will produce brittle tests.

I encourage you to join the [spectrum channel](https://spectrum.chat/react-testing-library) if you need help getting started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I wrote in my question, there's a problem with the ```expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled()``` assertion. I can find an input element easily, I can edit its value and see changes in DOM. But prop method is never called, according to RTL.

Comment: If I run your codesandbox the error I see is `Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="input"]`. If I apply one of the changes I suggested it works just fine

Comment: Just to make sure, are we talking about this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/y229669nvx ?
I've just opened it again and I see this error: 

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called.

Comment: Yes, that's the sandbox. You are probably seeing some local changes that you haven't pushed yet. The error I see is `Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="input"]` which makes sense if you look at the code you posted

Comment: @Gpx - I've already included that in my test (in the first sandbox). It still fails. As mentioned, the creator states not to assert against event handlers.

Comment: There's something weird here, I see a different error and changing the logic to find the input fixes the test for me. I'm running the sandbox in Chrome in a private window